# Web Platform Installer PHP Updates

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, php5

I have installed a version of PHP with the Microsoft Web Platform Installer v3.0.  In this case it was version 5.3.10 and since then version 5.4.0 has come out.  How do I use the Microsoft Web Platform Installer to update the version of PHP?  I cannot seem to find any documentation on this or what the recommend procedure should be.  This is on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.